# update database of an app from another app in android

Tags: java, android

I need to update and insert rows in Sqlite from another app. I am working on an android app and I have to update database of another app,how can I do that,is it possible to access and edit another app's database from my app.

Comment: Study Content providers in Android. This helps to share data across applications as well as modify

Answer (score 1):

You should look at Content Providers. From the android [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

> Content providers manage access to a structured set of data. They encapsulate the data, and provide mechanisms for defining data security. Content providers are the standard interface that connects data in one process with code running in another process.

[Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) explain how you can use it.

Comment: do i have to provide datas to access other apps

Comment: You have to have your database accessible via a contract , which is defined by creating a content provider. Only the apps that validate against the contract can request for read/update of the db in the app you have implemented the content provider.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to achieve. correct me if i am wrong. You are developing android application in which you are trying to update your application database by fetching data from some different database. right? if yes, you have to get details of the database server /database connection details from the database owner if possible. in case if the owner of the database is not providing or not ready to give  you credentials/database connection details then confirm whether they have any services/webAPI/web services through which they expose database data.
If they have webapi/webservices available then you can easily consume in your andriod application and do what ever operation you want to perform.

Hope this helps..